# Optimize nested loop in java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am about to generate an excel based on the user's request.

**Input**: 
`DateRange` - 2022/02/01-2022/02/07

**Scenario** 
The system will retrieve the logs from the database based on the `DateRange`. The logs contain the names of people & date when it was added. Also, the system will retrieve the list of people from the database. Now, after retrieving the logs and the people, I want to get the number of occurrence a person appeared on each date.

Database Info:

logs table - 10k or more 
person table - at least 1,500 people.

**Expected output:**
[image: First]

**Problem Issue**

From the given data above there is a possibility of `10,000(logs) * 1,500(person) = 15m` or more iteration to get the total occurrence of a person. This results to a heavy traffic on the response which took almost 60seconds or more.

Here is my code:

```
// initialize days
List<Date> days = getDaysFromRequest(); // get  the range from request

for (Person person: getPersonList()) {
  // .... code here to display Persons
  for (Date day: days) {
    // .... code here to display day
     int total = 0;
     for(UserLog log: getUserLog()) {
        if ( day == log.dateAdded && log.personName == person.Name) {
           total++; 
        }
     }
     System.out.printLn(total); // write total here in excel sheet Like,  B2 address
  }
}
```

How should I optimize this?

Comment: Probably you should do that within the database?

Comment: Beyond that, I dont get your exact requirements. What is the exact data structure you are creating there, as in what does `// write total here` mean? A first approach could be for example to NOT loop over the persons?! Instead, have a MAP < String, Integer > where the key is the name found in the log. And the value is the counter. So you just count all relevant days for all users, and then you use that information (later on). Or you go for a more complex data structure that allows you to increase counters for different days.

Comment: you can use multi threading. you can create two executers for two looping conditions (days loop and getUserLog loop).

Comment: @GhostCat  Which part? Will it be faster to retrieve data from the database while iterating for at least 45k? `1500(persons) * 30(days)=45k`

Comment: @GhostCat `A first approach could be for example to NOT loop over the persons?!` This is good but I have to get persons from the database on ORDER basis and not on Log basis. If you have better code, pls add your answer as it would be helpful. 
BTW, I edited my question. thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I get it right, all the information you want seems to be in the logs or if not it defaults to zero. Therefor I would do something like:

```
Map<String<Map<LocalDate,Long>> occurrenceByNameAndDate =  // Map<Username<Map<Date,Count>>

    userLogs.strream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(UserLog::personName,
                               Collectors.groupingBy(UserLog::dateAdded, 
                                    Collectors.counting())));
```

and use the above map some how like:

```
personList.forEach(person -> dateRange.forEach(day -> {
             long count = occurrenceByNameAndDate.getOrDefault(person.Name,Collections.EMPTY_MAP).getOrDefault(day,0);
             writeToExcel(person,day,count);
           }));
```

Or do it on the DB side

```
SELECT personName, dateAdded,COUNT(*) 
FROM UserLog 
WHERE dateAdded between(...)
GROUP BY personName,dateAdded
```